# perform comparison inside backticks

Tags: bash

Is it possible to do something akin to the following in a bash script?:

```
totaltrackseval=`if [[ $totaltracks -ge 0]]; then; echo '-N $totaltracks'; else; echo 'elsetext'; fi`
```

If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do what you want. You almost got it right the first time. Note the fact that I substituted your single quotes for double ones. Variable substitution doesn't work inside single quotes. Also, when you use the brackets for tests they require whitespace padding on the inside.

```
totaltrackseval=`if [ $totaltracks -ge 0 ];
                then
                    echo "-N $totaltracks"
                else
                    echo "elsetext"
                fi`
```

If you prefer a single-line implementation:

```
totaltrackseval=`if [ $totaltracks -ge 0 ]; then echo "-N $totaltracks"; else echo "elsetext"; fi`
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly.  I would've responded when I ticked it but it was 3am and I wanted to sleep :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, like this:

```
totaltrackseval=`bash -c "if [[ $totaltracks -ge 0 ]]; then echo '-N $totaltracks'; else echo 'elsetext'; fi"`
```

Test:

```
nelson@sev:~$ totaltracks=5
nelson@sev:~$ totaltrackseval=`bash -c "if [[ $totaltracks -ge 0 ]]; then echo '-N $totaltracks'; else echo 'elsetext'; fi"`
nelson@sev:~$ echo $totaltrackseval
-N 5
```

Comment: This will not work with the $totaltracks inside single quotes.

Comment: $totaltracks is inside single quotes in the TRUE part of the if, and this executes correctly, can you clarify why this wont work? a concrete example?

Comment: Because inside single quotes the $totaltracks reference will not be sustituted for the actual value with bash. Sample script:

Comment: @Tim: the single quotes here are just part of the double-quoted string; the parameter expansion occurs before the string is passed to bash.

Comment: I stand corrected! I missed the double quotes after `bash -c`

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach, using two types of parameter expansion. I am assuming that `totaltracks` is either unset or has a non-negative integer value.

```
# Use an alternate value for totaltracks if it is set
totaltrackseval=${totaltracks:+-N $totaltracks}

# Use a default text if totaltrackseval still has no value
: ${totaltrackseval:=elsetext}
```